# Spring batch multithreading

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch

Problem Statement: After successfully completion of spring job won't be able to access data from `ExecutionContext` which is set inside spring batch partition.

### Partition code:

```
for (String files : fileNameListmatch) {
            ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
            executionContext.putString("file", files);

            partitionData.put("partition: " + partitionNo, executionContext);
            partitionNo++;
        }
```

Inside partition code, I added list of files to `ExecutionContext`.

### JobListener code:

```
    @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['file']}") 
    String file;
    @Override
      public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                      for (String file1 : file) {
                                moveCSVFile = Files.move(Paths.get(inputFilePath + "/" + file1 + ".csv"),
                                        Paths.get(archiveFilePath + file1 + ".csv"));
                                moveCTLFile = Files.move(Paths.get(inputFilePath + "/" + file1 + ".ctl"),
                                        Paths.get(archiveFilePath + file1 + ".ctl"));
                        }   
    }
```

Inside `afterJob`, I tried to access list of files from `ExecutionContext` after completion of job.Getting null inside `ExecutionContext`.

After completion of job successfully, I have to move input files to another folder but won't be able to access files (getting null inside executionContext).  After completion of job I have to move input files to one folder to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different execution contexts: one at the step level and one at the job level. Make sure to use the job scoped one since you want to access the execution context from a job listener.

If you use the step scoped one, you can always promote keys to the job execution context using a `ExecutionContextPromotionListener`. Please refer to the [Passing Data to Future Steps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/index-single.html#passingDataToFutureSteps) section for more details.